# Switch branches in a git repo with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

What is the proper way to switch branches in a repo containing one or more submodules?

Consider all cases, maybe there is a different approach for each:

- submodules exist in only origin/destination branch
- one of the submodules contains un-pushed/un-committed/untracked files that you may want to keep
- submodules in origin/destination branch point to different sha1, with a different file set

At the moment, since all our submodules start with `x_*`, we have to do this to *safely* switch branches:

```
rm -rf x_*; rm -rf .git/modules/x_*
```

On top of being pretty *dirty* (to say the least), this is not safe with changes in the submodule (untracked files, un-pushed commits and modified files will be silently deleted)

**Example**: switching from branch `B1` with submodules `S1`, `S2`, `S3` to branch `B2` with submodules `S2` and `S4`

First we clone the repo and checkout `B1` and all its submodules. How can we swich to `B2` so that submodules `S1` and `S3` are not deleted from the files system (only show up as untracked files), `S2` is now on a different version and `S4` appeared in the file system as well?